Handling Null Values For Unmatched Rows in a Left Join SQL
Sorry for the horrible first part of the question. Tried to explain with example in second part.
I have two tables a, b. I am left joining these two tables based on three columns to retrieve a column 'description' from table b. Let's say these three columns are id, main_cat and sub_cat. If table a has a row that has a combination of id, main_cat, sub_cat that does not exist in table b, the description column is null.
How can I write a query so that if the description column is null after joining, to use column main_description from table b as description based on the id, main_cat value?
Example: let's illustrate this with an example:
Table a:
id   main_cat    sub_cat
------------------------
 1      A           X
 2      B           Y
 3      A           Z
 4      C           W

Table b:
id   main_cat    sub_cat    description        main_description
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      A           X       Description 1      Main Description A
 2      B           Y       Description 2      Main Description B
 4      C           W       Description 3      Main Description C

Desired result:
id  main_cat    sub_cat    description
---------------------------------------------
1      A           X       Description 1
2      B           Y       Description 2
3      A           Z       Main Description A
4      C           W       Description 3

Tried using COALESCE in the select statement and CASE WHEN, but failed.
Really sorry for the horrible wording and example structure. I did not know how else to ask. New to SQL, so the framing o the problem isn't great.
Tried something like below:
SELECT 
    A.ID, A.Main_cat, A.Sub_cat,
    (CASE 
         WHEN B.Description ISNULL 
             THEN B.MainDescription 
             ELSE B.Description 
     END) AS Description 
FROM  
    (SELECT * FROM tblA) AS A  
LEFT JOIN
    tblB AS B ON B.somevalue = 'somevalue' 
              AND B.Main_cat = A.Main_cat  
              AND B.Sub_cat = A.Sub_cat 
              AND A.ID = B.ID


COALESCE() certainly sounds like the right approach. How exactly did you try it, what was the result and why was it not what you expected?

Why does table b have different id data types? This might be easier to figure out if you used actual table formatting in your question

Please [edit] your question to provide details. Code does not belong in the comments

Different data type was a mistake. :( I'm so sorry for the mess of a question.
Added tried code to question. Cannot format code in comments.
I have tried something like this:
 SELECT A.ID ,A.Main_cat ,A.Sub_cat ,(case when B.Description ISNULL then B.MainDescription else B.Description end) as Description FROM (SELECT * FROM tblA) as A LEFT join tblB as B on B.somevalue = 'somevalue' and B.Main_cat=A.Main_cat and B.Sub_cat=A.Sub_cat and A.ID=B.ID 

If you're data was on different tables
SELECT  COALESCE(B.OtherDescription, A.Description, 'No Description') 'TheDescription', ISNULL(B.OtherDescription, A.Description) 'No Description2'
    FROM A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON ( A.id = B.id AND A.main_cat = B.main_cat AND A.sub_cat = B.sub_cat )

If you data is on the same table:
SELECT  COALESCE(B.OtherDescription, B.Description, 'No Description') 'TheDescription', ISNULL(B.OtherDescription, B.Description) 'No Description2'

I don't think you should be using a Case statement at all.  ISNULL may not work in all varieties of SQL but COALESCE should be pretty standard everywhere.

Thank you for bearing with the mess and actually answering.
The second value in your COALESCE will also have to be a column from B.
COALESCE does work. But it'll take up the third default value('No Description' in your code) and does not take the second column value from B. Maybe because that combination of the three columns does not exist in B it considers that as a null value as well.
And thanks again for bearing with me

Something like the following works if id, main_cat combinations do not have multiple sub_cat which in my case there is.
SELECT      a.id,     a.main_cat,     a.sub_cat,     COALESCE(b.description, main_b.main_description) AS description
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN
b ON a.id = b.id AND a.main_cat = b.main_cat AND a.sub_cat = b.sub_cat
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT id, main_cat, main_description FROM b) AS main_b
ON      a.id = main_b.id AND a.main_cat = main_b.main_cat
In my case there are multiple sub_cat. SO I still dont have any solution to my problem

The question is not fully clear when it comes to picking the secondary description. You say:

...to use column main_description from table b as description based on the id, main_cat value

In the example:

There won't be a match for (id, main_cat) = (3, 'A').
There will be two matches for (main_cat) = ('A').

I would assume it's the second case, and you want to pick the first match, according to the id.
If this is the case you can combine a lateral join with COALESCE(). For example:
select a.*, coalesce(b.description, x.main_description) as description
from a
left join b on b.id = a.id and b.main_cat = a.main_cat and b.sub_cat = a.sub_cat
left join lateral (
  select * from b where b.main_cat = a.main_cat order by id limit 1
) x on true

Result:
 id  main_cat  sub_cat  description        
 --- --------- -------- ------------------ 
 1   A         X        Description_1      
 2   B         Y        Description_2      
 3   A         Z        Main Description_A 
 4   C         W        Description_3      

See running example at db<>fiddle.
